# Let $n \geqslant 3$ and a polynomial $P(x) \in \mathbb{R}^*[x]$ such that $P(x) = x^n + ax + 1 \quad \text{for some } a \in \mathbb{R}^{*}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, complex-numbers, solution-verification

**Notation:** $\mathbb{R}^*:= $ the set of all non-zero reals.

---

---

$\blacksquare~$**Problem:** Let $n \geqslant 3$ be an integer and let $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{*}$. Consider the polynomial $P(x)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{*}[x]$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{C}[x]$ defined as
\begin{align*}
        P(x) ~=~ x^n + ax + 1 \quad \text{for some } a \in \mathbb{R}^{*} 
    \end{align*}
Let's consider the set $\Omega$ of all possible non-real roots of $P(x)$, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
        \Omega := \{  z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{R} ~:~ P(z) = 0\}
    \end{align*}
Prove that if $z$ $\in$ $\Omega$ then $z$ satisfies the inequality
\begin{align*}
        \lvert z \rvert ~\geqslant~ \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n - 1}}
    \end{align*}

---

---

$\blacksquare~$**My Approach:**
Let $z = r (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) \in \Omega~$ where $\theta \in (0, 2\pi)$. Then we get that
$$ P(z) = r^n (\cos n \theta + i \sin n \theta) + ar (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) + 1 = 0 $$
Now we have that both the Im$(P(z)) = 0$ and Re$(P(z)) = 0$. Thus $$ r^n \cos n \theta + ar \cos \theta + 1 = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad r^n \sin n \theta + ar \sin \theta = 0  $$
Thus on multiplying $\sin \theta$ to the Re$(z)$ part and $\cos \theta$ to the Im$(z)$ part and then subtracting we have that
$$ r^n | \sin (n - 1) \theta | = | \sin \theta |  $$
Then we have a claim.

---

$\bullet~$ **Claim:** the following inequality is valid for any $m \in N$.
$$ |\sin m \theta| \leqslant m |\sin \theta | $$
$\bullet~$ **Proof:** It's easy by induction on $m$. I'll just brief. Let the statement be denoted by $S(m)$ So, the base step is $m = 1$. And $P(m)$ is true.

Let's assume that for some $k = m$, the statement $P(m)$ is true. i.e., $$ |\sin k \theta| \leqslant k |\sin \theta| $$
Then from the following (by using)

1. $\color{red}{|\sin \theta| \leqslant 1 \text{ and } |\cos \theta| \leqslant 1}$,
   we have that
   $$ |\sin (k + 1)\theta| = |\sin k \theta \cos \theta + \cos k \theta \sin \theta | \leqslant \color{blue}{|\sin k \theta \cos \theta | + |\cos k \theta \sin \theta| } $$ $$ \leqslant |\sin k \theta | + |\sin \theta|$$
   $$ \leqslant k|\sin \theta| + |\sin \theta| = (k + 1)|\sin \theta | $$
   Thus $P(m)$ is true for $k + 1$ too. Hence the claim is proved.

---

Thus from our claim, we have that $$ r^n |\sin (n -1 )\theta| = |\sin \theta| \leqslant r^n (n - 1)| \sin \theta | $$
Thus
$$ r^n \geqslant \frac{1}{(n - 1)} \implies r \geqslant \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n - 1}} $$
Hence we have obtained that
$$ |z| \geqslant \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n - 1}}  $$
Completing the solution.

---

---

Is there any kind of glitch? Another solution will be appreciated.

Regards, Ralph.

Comment: In your induction proof, I am not convinced here: $|\sin k \theta \cos \theta + \cos k \theta \sin \theta | \leqslant |\sin k \theta + \sin \theta|,$ but it is possible to overcome it using 
$|\sin k \theta \cos \theta + \cos k \theta \sin \theta | \leqslant  |\sin k \theta \cos \theta | + |\cos k \theta \sin \theta|.$ 

The chain $r^n |\sin (n -1 )\theta| = |\sin \theta| \leqslant r^n (n - 1)| \sin \theta |$ seems a bit unclear, I would write 
$``{r^n |\sin (n -1 )\theta| = |\sin \theta|}$ and  ${r^n |\sin (n -1 )\theta|\leqslant r^n (n - 1)| \sin \theta |"}$

Comment: @user376343 It's exactly what I meant to do. But as I 'briefed' the solution, I did some step jumps. I basically used the bounds $|\sin \theta| \leqslant 1~$ and $~|\cos \theta| \leqslant 1$ and  (for the first part, the induction part) $$ |\sin k \theta \cos \theta + \sin \theta \cos k \theta |  
\leqslant |\sin k \theta \cos \theta| + |\cos k \theta \sin \theta| \leqslant | \sin k \theta | + |\sin \theta| $$ Then the next part, $|\sin \theta| = r^n|\sin (n - 1)\theta| \leqslant r^n (n - 1) |\sin \theta|$. Ig this will do :)

Comment: @Ralph Clausen Nice solution!

Comment: Thanks! @user376343. seems like I've been making a lot of typos recently (maybe due to lack of proper rest, dunno!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks fine to me. There is a typo at

> Now we have that both the Im$(z) = 0$ and Re$(z) = 0$.

which should be

> Now we have that both the $\operatorname{Im}(P(z)) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(P(z)) = 0$.

Also
$$
|\sin k \theta \cos \theta + \cos k \theta \sin \theta | \leqslant |\sin k \theta + \sin \theta|
$$
in the induction step is wrong, it should be
$$
|\sin k \theta \cos \theta + \cos k \theta \sin \theta | \leqslant
|\sin k \theta \cos \theta| +| \cos k \theta \sin \theta |\leqslant
|\sin k \theta |+ |\sin \theta|
$$

The first part of your proof can be shortened slightly if you divide the equation $z^n + az + 1 = 0$ by $z$ and take the imaginary part:
$$
 0 = \operatorname{Im} \left( z^{n-1} + a + \frac 1z \right)
= r^{n-1}  \sin (n - 1) \theta  - \frac 1r \sin \theta \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks! the first one was a typo and the second one was elaborated (at first I just briefed). And thanks for the 3rd one :)